# Start/Stop Service with C# Windows 8 app

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am brand new to Windows development, and am trying to create a Windows 8 app using C#/XAML. From my app, I want to stop an existing service. Is this possible? I have not been able to find any documentation on this...

Comment: If it's a regular WPF application, yes you can. The developer next to me is doing this as we speak.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't do things like that from a metro style app. You need to create a regular win32 app.

Comment: The OP doesn't mention Metro... It could be WPF?

Comment: he wouldn't say win8 if he didn't mean "windows store app"...

Comment: That is what I was afraid of. It is a metro style app, if that name is still used. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: @Wige The suggested usage is "windows store app"

Answer (score 0):

Look up the ServiceController API. It can be used within WPF applications. There's a Start and a Stop with the ability to check current status. It even allows you to connect to remote machines and control them that way.